# How do I set the expiration value for tempstore.private service?

Tags: 8

I am using the [tempstore.private](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/tempstore.private/8.7.x) service, which uses an expiration time of one week. I need to change this; changing it globally is fine.

There is an [`$expire`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21TempStore%21PrivateTempStore.php/property/PrivateTempStore%3A%3Aexpire/8.7.x) property, but I've no idea how I'm supposed to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expiration time is a parameter set in the service container. If you look at `core/core.services.yml` you will see the `tempstore.expire` parameter is set with a default value of 604800 seconds. This value is set when the container is compiled, and will be the same for all private tempstores.

There doesn't seem to be a way to set this in code or to override the parameter with a configuration setting, although I do see some issues in the core issue queue for adding that ability.

So apart from editing core.services.yml, you can override the `tempstore.private` service in your own module in order to customize the behavior.

Comment: Thank you, its not ideal but setting it in core.services.yml will be sufficient for me.

Comment: @thiokol, don't edit core.services.yml. Site-specific you can add the parameter to services.yml parallel to settings.php. Modules can add the parameter to mymodule.services.yml. Then it will be compiled into the container when you clear the cache.

Comment: Yes, services.yml is the right way to go. I didn't know about that.